# Facebook app access token posts are only visible to me and not my friends or followers?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-access-token

When I post to facebook using my App Access token, it is successfully posted and returns the post id. But I am the only person who can see the post on my wall, no body else can see the post. Please help me !?

Comment: Is your app out of developer mode …?

Comment: @CBroe I think my app is still in developer mode.. How can I get it out of developer mode ?

Comment: In your app’s settings in the app dashboard.

Comment: @CBroe I think that if I can get my app out of the Developer mode, it will work fine, but I don't know how to do it ? :'(

Comment: @CBroe Thnks alot man ;) In fact I just needed to go to Status & Review tab and allow make my app visible to general public.
I was struggling for days but you made my day man. Thnks alot :D

Comment: Why 3 downvotes? This is a valid question.

Answer (score 3):

In fact I just needed to go to Status & Review tab and allow make my app visible to general public.