# Posts published by my app are only viewable by me

Tags: facebook

I understand from previous discussions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23088660/facebook-app-access-token-posts-are-only-visible-to-me-and-not-my-friends-or-fol)) going through the review process and making the app live to the general public will fix this.

However my app is only for use by me and is not available on a public url.

Is there another approval process to go through whereby my app can publish publicly viewable updates to my pages alone?

Answer (score 0):

As previous discussions stated you just need to set the app to public by going to the Status and Review Tab, it said nothing about going through a review process. You don't need to go through the review process if only you are using the application.

[image: Change to public]